# VS Emulator for Android error with Hyper-V

Tags: visual-studio-2015, android-emulator, windows-10, visual-studio-emulator

When I try to run the Visual Studio emulator for Android I get the following error.

**"Unable to add user to the Hyper-V Administrators group. Exit code 2220"**

I am able to run the Windows Phone emulator without problem, so the administrators group is obviously present. Have tried to run as administrator with same result.

Running Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 on Windows 10 Anniversary update (14393.10).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating Hyper-V Administrators group in Windows 10](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34751196/creating-hyper-v-administrators-group-in-windows-10)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32021618/unable-to-add-user-to-the-hyper-v-administrators-group-exit-code-2220

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be related to the version of Windows you have or started with. You have to start with a Pro install. *Upgrading from Home to Pro is incomplete.*

I recently discovered if you start with the **MSDN Windows 10 (Multiple Editions), Version 1607** and install it, it defaults to the **Home** edition. Once you put in the Pro Key to upgrade it, it becomes "**Pro**"; but not really. The "**Users And Group**" snap-in will not work, you are stuck with the security model in "**Home**". Once you have upgraded, you need to **Reset** the installation -- but do not delete/format the partition or you get a "**Home**" edition again.

The MSDN version does not allow you to select **Home/Pro** and there is no **Pro** version to download. Very frustrating. MS has known about this for almost a year.

Some have postulated it is because they removed a Default group definition file that included **Hyper-V Administrators**, but I created the group in "**Home**" using a Net command and it still does not work.